# Why do Martians have to wear space helmets?

Tags: mars-attacks

In *Mars Attacks!*, it's established that Martians must wear those space helmets because, unlike us oxygen-breathing Earthlings, Martians must breathe nitrogen.

Is this a deliberate joke by the writers or just research failure? Because, of course, Earth's atmosphere is mainly nitrogen!

Comment: Oxygen is a dangerous toxin; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity

Comment: I do not know from the source, but the fact that they breathe nitrogen does not mean that other ingredients of air are not harmful to them. We breathe oxygen, but try breathing an air with a few % of CO2 or CO, even if oxygen is kept on the same level (21%) - you will die.

Comment: The massive release of oxygen in atmosphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxidation_Event lead to the exctinction of many anaerobic organisms

Comment: Possibly, but they never say Oxygen is harmful, just they breathe Nitrogen - in fact one martian was chewing gum made of highly concentrated Nitrogen, which is given as the reason s/he could breathe in Earth's atmosphere!

Comment: I always assumed it was a joke. A. It seems like quite a coincidence to choose nitrogen out of all possible elements, B. Air being mostly nitrogen is fairly common knowledge, so it's unlikely they just missed it, and C. The movie is a comedy, and making jokes is its business. It being a joke seems like a safe assumption, no?

Comment: +1 only because I love this movie. One of my favorite so-bad-it's-good movies of all time.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the actual Martian atmosphere is only [about 2.6% nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Mars). It's mainly carbon dioxide. Makes the idea even stranger.

Comment: *Rule Of Cool*.  'Nuff said!

Comment: @EdmundDantes to add in your comment: try breathing in an atmosphere where oxygen is higher, 50% or more ;)

Comment: I say capitulate, steal their nitrogen-biology technology, sell it to a venture-capital funded startup (which we, of course, are the founders of), get it to IPO, and make a fortune. So, millions die and the earth is left a wasteland. WE get filthy rich! WIN-WIN!!! :-)

Comment: @Edmund Dantes: You don't even have to change the composition, just increase the pressure.  For instance, when diving you start to run into oxygen toxicity problems below 60m/200 ft: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity#Underwater  So the helmets might serve to reduce Earth's atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Why would you wear a helmet on Mars?

Comment: @ggdx - I breathe oxygen and Mars does not have an oxygen rich atmosphere!

Comment: @colmde That pretty much answers your question then. Different atmospheres. Ours would be just as hostile to them as theirs is to us

Comment: @ggdx - No the point is Earth's atmosphere *is* Nitrogen rich

Answer (score 61):

[*Mars Attacks!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Attacks!) the film was based on [*Mars Attacks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Attacks), a set of trading cards (aka bubblegum cards) published by Topps in 1962.

[image: Card 1: The invasion begins]

The martians in the film are depicted with helmets because that's how they're depicted on the trading cards. Any other explanation is going to be an after-the-fact rationalization.

You can see images of the entire set of cards [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbEE.jpg). There's a paragraph on the back of each one explaining what each one was. None of the text directly addresses why the martians wear helmets on earth.

Cards 48 and later depict Martians on Mars living in domed cities, which could indicate that the Martian atmosphere is no longer ideal for their needs. But Martians are also shown outside the cities without helmets, so they can apparently operate in the martian atmosphere to some extent.

[image]
[image]

Humans are shown as needing breathing gear on Mars (with flak helmets on the inside, naturally), except for card 52 which is inside a Martian city.

[image]

Comment: Flak helmets on the _inside_ is ... _awesome_!

Comment: Fantastic answer. I had no idea that this was the origin of the Mars Attacks designs.

Comment: I always interpreted the city domes to be like defensive walls rather than for gaseous control.

Comment: Card 19 mentions that the Martians have oxygen lines on their suits.

Comment: Dangit! I was only five years old and my parents didn't let me have bubble gum! I'LL SUE!!!!!! :-)

Comment: My goodness... and people complain about gory MTG cards!

Comment: Card 45 was the one (where I grew up) that NOBODY could find. The older kids bought pack after pack of the gum but the cards were every number but 45.... This went on for a very long time

Answer (score 15):

We have confirmation from the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5353883-mars-attacks) that these helmets are linked to a "*life support backpack*". It stands to reason that Earth's atmosphere, while containing nitrogen, isn't directly supportive of their form of life.

> A dozen of Mars's finest marched in rows on either side of their
>   awesome Ambassador. These green creatures' long legs and arms were
>   ringed with jointed metal tubing. **Their chests were crisscrossed with
>   flexible hoses that joined domed helmets to life-support backpacks.**
>   The Martians carried toylike contraptions of tubes and spheres.

Based on the fact that the Martian infiltrator was able to survive by chewing a gum that was comprised of compressed nitrogen gas would suggest that the goal of the helmets is to provide an *exclusively nitrogen* (100%-ish) gas breathing environment and to *exclude* gases in Earth's atmosphere that would be poisonous to a Martian.

Answer (score 11):

Mars atmosphere versus Earth atmosphere...

1. Mars atmosphere is known to be much thinner than the oxygen/nitrogen rich Earth atmosphere, I think, containing mostly carbon dioxide, (anyone with more accurate knowledge feel free to correct me), so the inclusion of space helmets on the Martians in mars attacks is likely a reference to the fact that they are, well... hey, ... Martians.
2. If we reference the SF megatext different planets represent inimical  environments to invaders/non locals, think of the the Martians in HG Wells' *War of the Worlds* being undone by Earth bacteria.
3. In the film itself, one Martian is shown chewing gum that gives off highly concentrated nitrogen (please correct me if I am wrong, it is a long time since I watched this...) indicating they breathe pure nitrogen and not an oxygen nitrogen mix and again emphasizing that the Martians are not from Earth.
4. Rule of funny, the space helmets are deliberately ridiculous. This is not a film that cleaves close to actual science despite the fact that it was intended to feature a cameo by Carl Sagan. The bottom line is it's meant to be a comedy and is somewhat slapstick in its approach. Logic and scientific accuracy will always take second place to what seems funny.

Comment: Hey, you mean heads do not pop when listening to ridiculously high male voices? Well, maybe not literally, but...

Comment: #2 is (a spoiler) why they should have to.